# CKAN : Upload to datastore failed; 404 error

Tags: datastore, ckan

I try to upload a file into the DataStore but i got this http error :

[DataStORE Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjgAn.png)

The requested URL is : http://demo.ckan.org/dataset/72dba89d-c320-42b2-8733-5c5084f1213c/resource/4da87da1-755f-410b-9414-936d3c4edd9b/download/data.csv

But when i replace demo.ckan.org with the Ip adresse of my ckan machine i got the file.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would in general mean that DNS is not working as far as CKAN is concerned. Have you tried "ping demo.ckan.org" on the shell of the machine running CKAN?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Its OK.